# How to remove whitespace from <li>

Tags: html, css

I have this issue, I can't for the life of me try and remove the whitespace in this (li) tag, below I've include a screen capture, what I'm trying to do is remove the white before the grey menu bar, as well make the whole menu bar line up to bottom grey bar.

**CSS**

```
.menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
 left: 0px;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.menu li a {
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 161.3px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'MyriadPro', sans-serif;
 font-size: .875em;
 color: #FFF;
 height: 1.2em;
}

#MenuGreyBar li a{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 list-style: none;
 left: 0px;
 height: 1.2em;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <div>
    <ul id="MenuGreyBar">                        
      <li style="left: 0px;">
        <a href="#" class="bgGrey">&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="about_us.html" class="bgLightBlue">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href="Help_Support.html" class="bgMuddyGreen">Help & Support</a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href="Law_Info.html" class="bgGreen">Law & Information</a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... There are a few more. -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

The image: (it didn't let me embed)
http://db.tt/tcSr5kGv

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to remove the white space from your source files, or from the rendered HTML?

Comment: So the problem is on the top left where it's cut out?

Comment: Yup, I'm not exactly sure how to get rid of it

Comment: Try setting border, margin, and padding to 0px and see if that fixes the problem. Specifically, I don't see `padding: 0px;` under `#MenuGreyBar li a{`

Comment: @AlexW Thank You, that worked. Had to go back and adjust the space for each link. O well. I'll change it when I find a better way of doing, I guess right now that'll suffice. Thank You for your help.

Comment: For future reference, the simplest way to debug this type of problem is to use FireBug. It will show you the exact effective CSS for any element, and allow to see all the various style definitions that were combined to create the actual style used.  It is indispensable.  Chrome has similar functionality; not sure about IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if this is your issue, but here's my guess:

```
.menu li {

  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em; /* We set a left margin for all menu elements here
                              which will cause them to jut over. We want this for
                              most elements*/
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li a {

   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 161.3px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: 'MyriadPro', sans-serif;
   font-size: .875em;
   color: #FFF;
   height: 1.2em;
}

#MenuGreyBar li a{

  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1.2em;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;       /*The first menu item is special and needs no margin, so we try
                     to clear it, however we are clearing the anchor element in the li
                     block, and the margin is applied on the li block itself, so the li
                     block's margin is rendered before the anchor has any say*/
}
```

So what we need to do is clear the margin property on the actual `li` element, this code will do it:

```
#MenuGreyBar li{
 margin: 0;
}
```

That should do it, my best guess.

Comment: Aye, that's what I did couple minutes ago. Thanks anyway :)